# How to output multiple elements via AWS query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, aws-security-group

I trying to output in a column format three keys from 'rds'. If I start with this statement:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --region us-east-1 --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, PubliclyAccessible, VpcSecurityGroupId]' --output text
```

*...I get:*

> `DBId true none`

However, if I include another element to pull the security group:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --region us-east-1 --query 'DBInstances[*].VpcSecurityGroups[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, PubliclyAccessible, VpcSecurityGroupId]' --output text
```

*...I get:*

> `none none sg-id`

I am not quite sure why my first two columns now become *none* and the `sg-id` is presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is `VpcSecurityGroups[*]`:

```
'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, PubliclyAccessible, VpcSecurityGroupId]'
vs
'DBInstances[*].VpcSecurityGroups[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, PubliclyAccessible, VpcSecurityGroupId]'
```

In the second one, you are receiving `none` because `DBInstanceIdentifier` and `PubliclyAccessible` are not attributes of `VpcSecurityGroups`.

Here's a portion of an output to show the hierarchy:

```
{
    "DBInstances": [
        {
            "PubliclyAccessible": false,
            "VpcSecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Status": "active",
                    "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-1203dc23"
                }
            ],
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "mydbinstance-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Try this instead:

```
'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, PubliclyAccessible, VpcSecurityGroups[*].VpcSecurityGroupId]'
```

It won't look very pretty if there are multiple security groups, since it is a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately that removes the column structure and I am not able to 'awk' the true/false.

Comment: To ensure correct processing, it's better to receive output as JSON and process it either programmatically or with JQ -- this ensures you are receiving the correct data rather than relying on tabs, especially for one-to-many outputs.